# Object WCF receive null

Tags: c#, wcf

I have following object and it receives sometimes null, but when it receives null it crash with

> System.ServiceModel.FaultException: Object reference not set to an
>   instance of an object.

Anybody know how to fix it?

```
namespace Objects
{
    using System;
    using System.Runtime.Serialization;

    [DataContract]
    public class ObjectMgmt
    {
        private double? date;

        [DataMember]
        public double? Date
        {
            get
            {
                return this.date;
            }
            set
            {
                this.date = value;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You should show the Method code, not the object one :)

Answer (score 0):

Fault exception indicates an exception thrown by the server
during the processing of the request. you can either debug the server
, or add logs to it to diagnose the real problem.